# how to count number of line in a graph image using opencv python 3

Tags: python, opencv

I use `HoughLines` and `HoughCircles` to detect lines and circles of my graph image. My code is already fine to detect a circle shape. But, I don't understand why my code doesn't detect any line correctly. It detected some lines on the picture border but does not detect the correct lines in the graph picture. This is my code with input and output images sample.

**Input Image**

[image]

**My Code**

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv

img = cv.imread('autoload.jpg')
output = img.copy()

gray = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv.medianBlur(gray, 5)

circles = cv.HoughCircles(blur, cv.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 2, 100)
detected_circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
num_circle = 0

for (x, y ,r) in detected_circles[0, :]:
    num_circle = num_circle + 1
    cv.circle(output, (x, y), r, (0, 0, 255), 3)

edges = cv.Canny(gray,50,150,apertureSize = 3)
lines = cv.HoughLines(edges,1,np.pi/180,200)
num_line = 0

for line in lines:
    num_line = num_line + 1
    rho,theta = line[0]
    a = np.cos(theta)
    b = np.sin(theta)
    x0 = a*rho
    y0 = b*rho
    x1 = int(x0 + 1000*(-b))
    y1 = int(y0 + 1000*(a))
    x2 = int(x0 - 1000*(-b))
    y2 = int(y0 - 1000*(a))
    cv.line(output,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(255, 0, 0),3)

print("Number of Node:",num_circle)
print("Number of Edge",num_line)

output = cv.resize(output, (500, 750))
cv.imshow('output',output)
cv.waitKey(0)
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

**Output Image**

[image]

Comment: the output of the console was like this `Number of Node: 8` `Number of Edge 6`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cv.HoughLinesP` instead, I'm doing it roughly below, it gives duplicate results that you can filter by proximity for example, or find better parameters than what I used.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv

img = cv.imread('image1.png')
output = img.copy()

gray = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

edges = cv.Canny(gray, 50, 150, apertureSize=5)
lines = cv.HoughLinesP(edges, 1, np.pi/180, 100, 
                       minLineLength=30, maxLineGap=2)
num_line = 0

for line in lines:
    num_line = num_line + 1
    x1,y1,x2,y2 = line[0]
    cv.line(output,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(255, 0, 0),3)

print("Number of Edge",num_line)

output = cv.resize(output, (500, 750))
cv.imshow('output',output)
cv.waitKey(0)
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image]

Comment: It is still not precise, the result must be 7 for the Edge (line) of the graph